# Problem solving or question answering

Tags: secondary-education, problem-solving, vocabulary

*What can be the most appropriate way of asking , Solve the problem or answer the question ?* 
As common usage in examinations we have question papers for all subjects. Therefore like in other subjects we normally use to say answer following questions but I suggest specifically from secondary education it's much better to say solve following problems rather than asking to answer questions. I would like to get your attention to maths olympiad question papers, there they present mathematics challenges as problems. 
By the meaning, *problem* is a difficulty that has to be resolved or dealt with but *question* is a sentence, phrase or word which ask for information.
To find the best solution to a problem you need to ask questions and questions can be created even by the solution of a problem too. 
 I would like to share my personal experience regarding the difference between question answering and problem solving. Very recently when I came across an IQ challenge related to moving ants along sides of a triangle I asked the question to myself what if we do this for any convex polygon and then what about if ants are allowed to move along diagonals too. Eventually by the way I questioned myself I could able to introduce a new concept and could able to publish 12 integer sequences on OEIS.

Comment: I think there may be two reasons for downvoting this issue , one is considering this issue is not relevant to this community other one is not considering there is much difference between the two terms. Anyway I think as maths educators we need to give reasons for our conclusions and most importantly we can't stick to the past just because that was the way things were explained to us. I posted this issue believing this community is the best platform to do so .

Comment: What language do you teach in? (I agree with @Tommi's answer that something like this is very language-dependent.)

Comment: @SueVanHattum I teach in English and Sinhala, as you know this issue is relevant to English and it is widely used international language all around the world .

Comment: @SueVanHattum , in Sinhala language too we have the same issue may be because of following the way it is stated in other subjects. You see actually now I'm answering your question and not solving.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly highly language-dependent.
In Finnish I would expect to read "tehtävä", while in Scandinavic languages "oppgave/opgave/oppgåva" (not sure of Swedish), all of which might be translated to a task, or a thing to be done. To my ears a problem could mean something negative; an issue, a thing that is wrong.

But regardless of the conventional use of the words, they quickly take on their own particular meaning in the context of mathematics exams. It is a pretty strong context and there is lots of jargon in the school world anyway. I doubt there is a much confusion caused or a large effect in what kinds of things pupils or students write down or draw as a result of this one word.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views on this issue, definitely two terms have two different meanings and as maths educators we better think of what we are doing . As an example if I ask what is your profession that is a question and for that you can answer because there you don't have anything to solve.

Comment: This is for further clarification, actually my issue here is regarding much appropriate way . Sometimes it may not have much impact on the way now we are used to do. For an example we have meteorology department but it's not involving in anything related to meteors. After realizing it, only few countries changed the terms to weather department. Here also you can say there is no much impact but we need to do things meaningfully.